# Why am I removing an element from the wrong ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am seeing some behaviour that I can't quite make sense of and was wondering if someone would be kind enough to explain exactly what is going on here. This is the code I currently have.

```
public class MyClass {

    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public MyClass() {
        populate();
        removeData(myList);
    }

    private void populate() {
        myList.add("Some data");
        myList.add("Some more data");
        myList.add("Even more data");
    }

    private void removeData(ArrayList<String> list) {
        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        temp = list;
        temp.remove("Some data");
    }
}
```

Now for some reason, after I run this code, data is being removed from the ArrayList "myList". Why is this happening even though I am only supposed to be removing data from a variable inside the method "removeData" and not from the field "myList"?

Comment: but you assigned `temp = list` so basically the references are pointing to the same object

Comment: Java assign object references, you need to read more about Java and Object Oriented programming basics

Comment: Because templist=mylist is assigning reference of mylist to templist.so whatever you do on templist will effect mylist.

Comment: whats the point of creating temp when you still point to list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 temp = list;
```

Even though you are removing inside the method, you are still pointing to a instance member, hence it can see the changes.

You need to create a new list with that values if you don't want to affect the instance member.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to:

```
private void removeData(ArrayList<String> list) {
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(list);
    temp.remove("Some data");
}
```

and you'll get your desired behaviour (though it doesn't really make much sense). Assigning `list` to `temp` does not copy the items in the list, but assigns just a reference to the same area of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Java works with references, so when you assigned `temp = list`, both variables pointed to the same object. Instead, you want to make a copy of `list`:

```
private void removeData(ArrayList<String> list) {
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(list); // Make a copy
    temp.remove("Some data");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    temp = list;
```

In the first line you are creating new list. Till that point its fine. But in the next line you are referring `list` to `temp`. So earlier object to which `temp` was referring will be garbage collected `temp` will be referring to the same object which  was  created  `Myclass` constructor